# Understanding Users on Realm Object Server

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I recently set up a Realm Object Server on Digital Ocean. I configured the server to use Facebook authentication.

I then wrote a simple iOS App to login with the Facebook iOS SDK and then I use Realm to login like this

```
let credentials = SyncCredentials.facebook(token: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: URL(string: "http://000.000.00:9080/")!, onCompletion: { (user, error) in
   print("User: \(user)")
   print("Error: \(error)")
})
```

It works! Cool. I see these default realm's on my Object Server.

[image]

My understanding of these realms is that they are there for me to configure administrator / developer access. Am I wrong about this?

The User I just created got added to the `/_admin` realm. Why? They are a user of my app, not any sort of admin. If this is the appropriate place for the user can I add other data under `/_admin` -> `User` object? How do I prevent the user from being created under `/_admin` and created under my own `User` object? Am I not understanding the Realm Object Server Architecture in this case?

Answer (score 0):

These realms are maintained by Realm Object Server and you should avoid writing to them in any way at the risk of breaking things on the server. It is my understanding that reading from them is ok.

The user shows up in `/__admin` not because the user *is* an administrator, but because that's the data storage ROS uses to store its users.

If you are familiar with a relational database like SQL Server, this is equivalent to system-maintained tables like `sysusers` and `syslogins`.

Comment: So after I call `SyncUser` with the Facebook credentials I should just let ROS do its thing with that new account? Then it's up to me to maintain my own Realm of users on the ROS?

Comment: That sounds like the safest bet to avoid changing a ROS-managed realm in some way that causes problems down the road.